Selection tools in Edit mode not working
In one of my Blender files all the selection tools (select box, select circle, select lasso), as well as selecting by clicking, outside of Vertices selection mode (edges and faces), DON'T work. Functions like select all, select random or checker deselect DO work. The tools DO work in Object mode.
I have tried adding a new cube into the scene. It doesn't work on it either. Other Blender files work. I think I might have activated something by accident. Any ideas what this could be?
Gif that shows the isssue:


There was a question a short while ago where someone could not select parts of the mesh. Your issue looks a bit different but without seeing your actual file it is hard to tell for me what is going on there. Check out my answer on the other question if there is any useful information for you: Can't select or edit certain parts of my mesh during retopo

Thank you for the idea. I have checked, but it is not the issue I'm facing. I understand that it's not more than a guess without the file, but I can't share it. I have tried to recreate it and if I do, I will share the file.

I recommend you to reset your Blender settings:
File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings

*If it's not enough:
(After you've reset the settings):

Create a new Blender file

Append to new file all objects from your current project: File > Append

Save the new file


